# MediaElement with rounded corner in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, mediaelement

I like to create rounded corner for my video in Windows phone 8 app development.How to get this?

I have tried this below code

```xml
<Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF000000" CornerRadius="20" Padding="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="mask" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=CornerRadius}"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <VideoBrush SourceName="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                        </Grid.OpacityMask>
                        <MediaElement x:Name="Media" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="236" Source="/Assets/Videos/empty.m4v"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
```